# How to display attendance status for a month from the database?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and currently working on a school management system, particularly on an attendance module. In this module after daily roll call attendance of the teachers, their status in the TeachersAttedance table changes to either Present, Late or Absent.

I'm able to submit teacher attendance status of the day in the  TeachersAttedance table in the model. The problem is now on how to retrieve this data and show it in a table format considering days of the month as the header in the table.

Essentially I want to show the teachers attendance on each day in the table depending on which month the user selects. Currently, I'm having a problem finding the solution to this.

here is my **views.py**

```
def teacher_attendance_report(request):
context = {}
form = TeacherAttendanceForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('group_by'):
        grab_data_passed = request.POST.get('group_by')
        #create caledar with days of the grabbed month
        z=0
        range=32
        days=[]
        if z< range:
            dats = TeacherAttendance.objects.filter(date__month=grab_data_passed)[z].date
            z+=1
            y=dats.month
            x=dats.year
            cal = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.WEDNESDAY)
            for day in cal.itermonthdays(x, y):
                days.append(day)
            context['days']=days    

        teacher = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)
        get_attendance=TeacherAttendance.objects.filter(date__month=grab_data_passed)
        context['get_attendance']=get_attendance  
        context['teachers'] = teacher
        return render(request, 'Reports/teacher_attendance_report_details.html', context)
context={'form':form}
return render(request, 'Reports/teacher_attendance_report_index.html', context)
```

here is the teacher attendance table that am using.
**models.py**

```
class TeacherAttendance(models.Model):
teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
date = models.DateField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ATTENDANCE)
objects = models.Manager()

class Meta:
    default_permissions = ('view', 'add', 'change', 'delete')
    ordering = ["date", ]
    get_latest_by = "date"
```

and this is how I'm implementing the template
**attendance.html**

```
 <table id="datatable-responsive"
                           class="datatable-responsive table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                     <tr>   
                    <th>Teacher <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down" z></i> - Date <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></th>
                    {% for day in days%}{% if day > 0%}<th>{{day}}</th> {% endif %}
                    {%endfor%}
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                     {% for teacher in teachers %}
                      <tr>
                       <td>{{ teacher }}</td>
                       {% for details in get_attendance %}
                       {% for day in days %}
                        {% if day == details.date.day %}
                        <td>{{ details.status }}</td>
                         {% else %}
                         <td>--</td>
                        {% endif %}
                       {%endfor%}
                       {%endfor%}
                      </tr>
                      {%endfor%}
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I'm currently getting a table with just statuses that don't correspond to the attendance status of each teacher. The other problem is that there are more columns of values than days (marked red in the image).

Any advice is really welcome, thank you so much.
[image: What am currently getting in the browser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making intensive research on this matter, i decided to return only dates on which teacher, student and the employees attended in a table format and it worked well